# Show random number every week

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show a random number between 1,000 and 1,999 and show that number for a week (Mondays for example). Then next week, generate a new number for that week.

The code below generates a random number, but no commas and no storage. Any help?

```js
var minNumber = 1001;
var maxNumber = 1997

weeklyNumber(minNumber, maxNumber);

function weeklyNumber(min,max)
{
    alert(Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min));
}
```

```html
<span class="weekly-count"></span>
```

Comment: Will you be opening and closing the program? You will need to know HTML web storage.

Comment: same number for all users? Or same number for individual user that my differ from other users? Objective is lacking detail

Comment: - The same number will be shown to all users.

Comment: - A cookie is needed to store the number correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var minNumber = 1001;
     var maxNumber = 1997;


     if (!localStorage.getItem("ran") && !localStorage.getItem("myTime") ) {

         var d = Date.now();
         var RandomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*(maxNumber-minNumber+1))+minNumber);

         localStorage.setItem("ran",RandomNum);
         localStorage.setItem("myTime",d);

     }


     else {

         var newTime = Date.now();
         var oldTime = localStorage.getItem("myTime");

         if(newTime - oldTime > 7*24*60*60*1000) { 

             RandomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*(maxNumber-minNumber+1))+minNumber);
             localStorage.setItem("ran",RandomNum);
             localStorage.setItem("myTime",newTime);

         }

     }

     $(".weekly-count").text(localStorage.getItem("ran"))

 })
```

Here is [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7p2rb865/3/)

Comment: Great that works for generating the number. What about storing it for a week?

Comment: Can anyone provide an example of that? With this method the number will be different for each visitor. We want to store and show the same number for all visitors.

Comment: `setInterval` for  week doesn't make any sense. If I open page and leave it every day it would never run

Comment: Run Demo then Close the browser tab (or window), and try again.

Comment: same problem only updating on monday...what if i visit site every day except monday

Comment: @trying_to_learn says:"generate a new number for that week", so code generate random number after 7 days.

Comment: A new number is shown every time and is not stored :/ Tried different browsers also.

Comment: demo work fine,your browser must support local storage.if my post help you mark it or at least upvote please.

Comment: But it will show a different number to each visitor. It should show the same universally to all visitors weekly.

Comment: You must use php or asp.net if you want show same number for all visitors.

Comment: I found this, but not sure how to make every Monday and add commas for a large number. Number between 1,000-2,000. https://www.webmasterworld.com/php/4125832.htm